# Self-referencing entity circular dependency happening just on EF Core 6.0

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

**Description**

I think this is an EF Core 6.0 bug, but I wanted to check here before submitting a bug to the EF Core GitHub repo.

I'm not sure at all if this is a bug. At least I think is an unexpected behavior.

This behavior appeared for the first time after migrating to .NET 6. I've managed to reproduce the issue in the simple project composed of the 3 files shown bellow. First I thought it was a breaking change so I reviewed all of them. However, I'm unable to find any breaking change that would cause this error. As I wasn't able to relate the error to any change I started changing EF Core version in my `.csproj` file. As soon as I change to 6.0.0-rc.2.21480.5 for all the packages (EF Core) the error doesn't show up anymore.

Another thing to highlight is that if I add a `SaveChanges` after the removes in the program.cs file the error won't happen either.

Do you think it's a bug or am I missing a new feature or breaking change?

`Person.cs`:

```
#nullable disable
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public Person Parent { get; set; }

    protected Person()
    {
    }
    
    public Person(string name, Person parent)
    {
        this.Name = name;

        if (parent is not null)
        {
            this.Parent = parent;
        }
    }
}
```

`Context.cs`:

```
#nullable disable
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context()
    {}

    public DbSet<Person> Parents { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
            "Data Source=DES04;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=true");        
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Parent)
            .WithMany()
            .IsRequired(false)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasKey(p => p.PersonId);
    }
}
```

`Program.cs`:

```
var context = new Context();

var parent = new Person("1", null);
var child1 = new Person("2", parent);
var child2 = new Person("3", parent);
var grandchild1 = new Person("4", child1);
var grandchild2 = new Person("5", child1);
var grandchild3 = new Person("6", child2);
var grandchild4 = new Person("7", child2);

context.Add(parent);
context.Add(child1);
context.Add(child2);
context.Add(grandchild1);
context.Add(grandchild2);
context.Add(grandchild3);
context.Add(grandchild4);
context.SaveChanges();

context.Remove(parent);
context.Remove(child1);
context.Remove(child2);
context.Remove(grandchild1);
context.Remove(grandchild2);
context.Remove(grandchild3);
context.Remove(grandchild4);

parent = new Person("1", null);
child1 = new Person("2", parent);
child2 = new Person("3", parent);
grandchild1 = new Person("4", child1);
grandchild2 = new Person("5", child1);
grandchild3 = new Person("6", child2);
grandchild4 = new Person("7", child2);

context.Add(parent);
context.Add(child1);
context.Add(child2);
context.Add(grandchild1);
context.Add(grandchild2);
context.Add(grandchild3);
context.Add(grandchild4);
context.SaveChanges();
```

**Stack trace**:

> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to save changes because a circular dependency was detected in the data to be saved: 'Person [Deleted]Person [Deleted] Parent { 'ParentId' } <-
> Person [Deleted] Parent { 'ParentId' } <-
> Person [Deleted]To show additional information call 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging'.'.
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Multigraph`2.ThrowCycle(List`1 cycle, Func`2 formatCycle, Func`2 formatException)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Multigraph`2.BatchingTopologicalSort(Func`4 tryBreakEdge, Func`2 formatCycle)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.CommandBatchPreparer.TopologicalSort(IEnumerable`1 commands)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.CommandBatchPreparer.BatchCommands(IList`1 entries, IUpdateAdapter updateAdapter)+MoveNext()   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IList`1 entries)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IList`1 entriesToSave)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(StateManager stateManager, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.<>c.b__104_0(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 t)   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges()
> at Program.$(String[] args) in C:\Users\Dev04\Desktop\Nueva carpeta\test\Program.cs:line 44

**Version information**

- EF Core: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` 6.0.0
- Database provider: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` 6.0.0
- Target framework: .NET 6.0.0

Comment: As suggested in error message, `EnableSensitiveDataLogging` and then post the error message again. I can't tell from this: `Person [Deleted]Person [Deleted] Parent { 'ParentId' } <- Person [Deleted] Parent { 'ParentId' } <- Person [Deleted]` which cycle is detected.

Comment: Hi, definitely a bug - reproduced it, `SaveChanges` after removes works as you said, also works if `Remove`s are called in the "right" order (first leaf, then parents - shortly, in reverse order of adding). Please go and report it.

Comment: I have EnableSensitiveDataLogging enabled and i'm not getting ANYTHING for the cycle detected but the error is there.  So blocking, I literally can't add features to my product right now.

Comment: @MicahOsborne I reported the error on https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26750 It's fixed on 6.0.2 which will be released in february