# EF Core 6 - System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to save changes because a circular dependency was detected in the data to be saved

Tags: ef-core-6.0

for the sake of simplicity, let say I have to projects:

- WebAPI and
- UnitTest for WebAPI

Both projects were using EF Core 5. WebAPI uses SqlServer and UnitTest uses the Sqlite (inMemory). Both projects work correctly.

I migrated from EF Core 5 to EF Core 6 and now WebAPI works correctly but I can't execute any of my Unit Tests. I get the following error:

> **System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to save changes because a
> circular dependency was detected in the data to be saved:
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Operations.CreateTableOperation**
> -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Operations.CreateTableOperation
> -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Operations.CreateTableOperation
> -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Operations.CreateTableOperation'..
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Multigraph`2.ThrowCycle(List`1
> cycle, Func`2 formatCycle, Func`2 formatException)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Multigraph`2.TopologicalSort(Func`4
> tryBreakEdge, Func`2 formatCycle, Func`2 formatException)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Multigraph`2.TopologicalSort(Func`4
> tryBreakEdge)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Sort(IEnumerable`1
> operations, DiffContext diffContext)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.GetDifferences(IRelationalModel
> source, IRelationalModel target)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabaseCreator.GetCreateTablesCommands(MigrationsSqlGenerationOptions
> options)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabaseCreator.CreateTables()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabaseCreator.EnsureCreated()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.EnsureCreated()

The circular reference seems to happen inside Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Operations.CreateTableOperation and since the WebAPI project works, I assume that this is a problem with the Sqlite provider.

The error seems to happen when the EF Configurations are executed inside the **OnModelCreating** method of DbContext. At this point, no attempted to save/update and entity has been made. The unit test fails during the EF configuration.

At this point I am clueless about how to proceed. We have around 100 configurations and there is no more information provided in the exception. Since everything was working on EF Core 5, I am assuming it is either a breaking change (specific to Sqllite) or a bug in EF Core 6.

Has anybody run into this issue? o does anybody have any ideas about how to figure out what the cause of the problem is?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, today as was looking at different issue (EF Core bug?) at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70012349/self-referencing-entity-circular-dependency-happening-just-on-ef-core-6-0. It's in different area, but the exception is thrown by the same `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Multigraph` class mentioned here. So it might be a common bug in the "topological sort" algorithms they are using. Hence you'd better go and report it in their GitHub issue tracker and see what they'll say.

Comment: I have this same issue, where you able to find anything on this?

Comment: @MicahOsborne, Unfortunately, we couldn't find a solution. We assumed it was a problem with the SqlLite provider being relatively new and decided to stay on .net 5 for now and wait for .net 6 to mature a bit more.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in version 6.0.2 I can confirm.